# Direct Traffic Google Analytics 100% Bounce Rate Less Than a Second on Page

Tags: google-analytics

Recently in some of my web properties I've noticed that there have been a very large uptick in what seems like some sort of odd spam. It is all direct traffic to the homepage lasting less than one second, all new users. I have sorted them by network in the image below and there seem to be about 9 offenders (at least for this web property). The traffic doesn't always have a common geographic location, but sometimes does. I realize I could set up rules to filter this traffic, but that would also filter out some legitimate traffic.

What exactly could this traffic be representative of? Spiders gone awry, useless bots?

What are solutions others have used to mitigate similar data anomalies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've also just turned on the 'filter bots from reports' setting in analytics. Admin / View column - view settings / Bot Filtering. after reading this... https://www.ohow.co/common-causes-of-unnatural-spikes-in-direct-traffic-google-analytics/

Comment: Did you really mean to write two separate answers to the same question?

Comment: I guess thinking about it, they could be combined. But if you think there's a single "silver bullet" answer to the question, I'd disagree. It can be a due to various different causes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to check this traffic based on hostname dimension. If you see many hosts other then yours, or (not set) values, then it's very likely to be a result of so-called referral spam. These hits were pushed into Analytics from devices other than your site. There are several methods to prevent this happening, e.g. by adding an Analytics View filter, that prevent hits of other Hostnames to appear in your reports.

Comment: Filtered by hostname to only the properties web domain, none of the above was changed. Less than 3% of the overall traffic was through a different domain, and none of it was the direct traffic I listed above.

Comment: Can you identify any other common characteristic of this high-bouncing direct traffic? E.g. common landing page, device type, OS/browser specific dimension values? That might give you the clue to identify the source of these hits.